# Cannot uninstall or update the CLI

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-cli

I am running Worklight 6.2 on Mac. I downloaded the latest fix from fix-central (6.2.0.0-WL-CLI-IF201408251637.zip). When I wanted to install the new version of the CLI, the installer got stuck around 33%. So after that I tried to uninstall the current installed version. The uninstall shows the uninstall dialog, but gets stuck at 0%. How can I get around this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you add any custom file/folder to your /Applications/IBM/Worklight-CLI directory?

Comment: No, I did not add custom files or folders.

Comment: I had the same issue while upgrading to 6.2.0.0.1 and I did the same as you have mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the complete /Applictions/IBM/Worklight-CLI directory. After that the installation of the new version succeeded.